# Understanding the CDF graphically

Tags: probability, data-visualization, cumulative-distribution-function

Given the following plot of a CDF $F(x)$
[image]

I'm testing my understanding on the graphs of the CDF, trying to figure it out certain probabilities but I'm still not grasping it.

For example my thoughts are the following for these probabilities.

$P\left(X=-1\right)=0.1$

$P\left(X<0\right)=F\left(0^-\right)=0.1$

$P\left(X\le 0\right)=F\left(0\right)=0.2$

$P\left(X=1\right)=0.3$

$P\left(0<X\le 3\right)=F\left(3\right)-F\left(0\right)=0.8-0.2=0.6$

$P\left(0<X<3\right)=F\left(3^-\right)-F\left(0\right)=0.6-0.2=0.4$

$P\left(0\le X\le 3\right)=F\left(3\right)-F\left(0^-\right)=0.8-0.1=0.7$

$P\left(1<X\le 2\right)=F\left(2\right)-F\left(1\right)=0.3-0.3=0$

$P\left(1\le X\le 2\right)=F\left(2\right)-F\left(1^-\right)=0.3-0.3=0$

$P\left(X>5\right)=1-P\left(X\le 5\right)=1-F\left(5\right)=1-1=0$

$P\left(X\ge 5\right)=1-P\left(X<5\right)=1-F\left(5^-\right)=1-0=1$

$P\left(3\le X\le 4\right)=F\left(4\right)-F\left(3^-\right)=0.8-0.6=0.2$

I'm not entirely sure about some of them. Like $P(X=1)$ and some other values. So, I would like to know if my understanding is correct or if I'm missing something, any destructive correction would be well received hehe.

Because I'm also thinking that

$P\left(0<X\le 3\right)=P\left(X<3\right)-P\left(X<0\right)=0.8-0.1=0.7$

$P\left(0<X<3\right)=P\left(X<3\right)-P\left(X=-1\right)=0.6-0.1=0.5$

$P\left(0\le X\le 3\right)=P\left(X\le 3\right)-P\left(X\le 0\right)=0.8-0.2=0.6$

$P(3≤X≤4)=P(X≤4)−P(X≤3)=0.8−0.8=0$

$P(X≥5)=1−P(X<5)=1−1=0$

And I'm not entirely sure about which ones are correct

Comment: $P(X=1)=0$, though it does not look like you made the same mistake elsewhere with the point probabilities at CDF locations that are continuous (discontinuity at $X=3$ but not at $X=1$, for instance).

Comment: @Dave I see, it's because is a mixed random variable right? I also was thinking that $P(0<X≤3)=P(X≤3)-P(X<0)=P(X≤3)-P(X=-1)=0.8−0.1=0.7$ But that would be wrong right?, $P(0<X≤3)=F(3)−F(0)=0.8−0.2=0.6$ and this is correct.  Or also $P(3≤X≤4)=F(4)−F(3−)=0.8−0.6=0.2$ would be $P(3≤X≤4)=P(X≤4)-P(X≤3)=0.8-0.8=0$

Comment: Review your answer to $P(X\ge 5).$

Comment: @whuber $P(X≥5)=1−P(X<5)=1-1=0$ right?